# Passing an array as bash variable

Tags: bash

I am submitting a series of batch jobs in a bash script.

The batch script `(script.sh)` is as follows:

```
samtools merge $1 $2
```

`$1` is the output and it is only one single file. So, it is no problem.

`$2` is the input but it is not only one file, it is several files and it is different in every directory. The bash script is as follows:

```
for i in directory1 directory2 
do
cd $i
d=$(echo *specific_prefix.txt)
echo $d
sbatch script.sh ${i}.output $d
cd ..
done
```

Running as above, the batch script only takes the first element of `$d` as its variable. Is there a way for a bash variable (`$2`) to take varying number of variables, for example for it to be a list whose length can be determined in another variable?

Edit:

I have the sbatch job script `(merge.sh)` as:

```
#!/bin/bash -l

arg1="$1"
shift 1
arg2=("$@")

samtools merge arg1 arg2
```

And I run it using a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash -l

for i in directory
do
cd $i
d=$(echo *RG.sort.dedup.bam)
sbatch merge.sh ${i}.output $d
cd ..
done
```

The error is: `samtools merge: fail to open "arg2": No such file or directory`

What could be the error in the script? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry don't know what is `samtools`. Also you need to use `samtools merge "$arg1" "${arg2[@]}`. Also I don't know what is `sbatch` before `merge.sh`

Comment: I made the changes you suggested and it is working now! Thank you very much! `samtools` is just the name of a programme in bioinformatics and `sbatch` is a command we use to submit batch jobs into our computer cluster. Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `shift` command after storing fixed arguments and use `$@` as below script. You can use a shell array to store variable number of arguments starting from 3rd position.

```
# store first 2 arguments in variables
arg1="$1"
arg2="$2"

# using shift 2 discard first 2 arguments
shift 2

# now store all remaining arguments in an array
arg3=("$@")

# examine our variables
declare -p arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Now run it as:

```
./script.sh merge abc foo bar baz
declare -- arg1="merge"
declare -- arg2="abc"
declare -a arg3='([0]="foo" [1]="bar" [2]="baz")'
```